# How to tell systemd to start a service after a clean exit of another service

Tags: systemd, services, exit-status

I'm trying to start a systemd. service after another service exits properly (e.g : in a application it could be `exit(EXIT_SUCCESS)`  ).

I've seen that there might be an **OnSuccess** option in the later release of systemd, but I would like to be able to do it without that option since my version of systemd doesn't support it.

Is it possible to do such thing properly?

Comment: The normal ordering rules don't work if the first service exits? I wonder if it would help to change the first service to use "RemainAfterExit"?

Comment: I'm new to systemd, but looking at the documentation, it seems that adding "RemainAfterExit=yes" will keep my application active (at least from the point of view of systemd), which is not exactly the behavior I expect. But maybe I'm wrong.
If it is the case, could you please expand a little bit on your suggestion?

Comment: The idea is to "(specify) whether the service shall be considered active even when all its processes exited" -- meaning the first service exits successfully, "but" the service itself is considered Active, such that the subsequent service can start/run. Is "keeping the first service active" a problem?

Comment: Now I get it, thanks for the explanation.
Even though it might not be an issue to have the first service still active in the sight of systemd,
I'm not quite sure how it will trigger the start of the second service.
I was counting on systemd to detect that the first service is finished to start the second one, but if it stays active, I don't know how to tell systemd to still do it :(

Comment: I can't test this right now, but the idea would be: Service1: RemainAfterExit=True; Service2: After=Service1.

Comment: Okayyyy! Now I see! I can test it and see it does the job. Thanks !

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/130875/discussion-between-sashavr-and-jeff-schaller).

Comment: Would you like to post your own answer with the details of the solution?

Comment: Sorry for being late. Actually, your solution might work in the case you described but not exactly the one I have.
I forgot to give you more context about what I'm trying to do.
Actually, service 1 is started at boot up. It presents a kind of launcher the screen that allows you to start service A, B, C or D. 
And once service A, B,C or D is terminated (clean or unclean way) it goes back to service 1. So, your solution might work on some cases, and I'm thankful to you because I might use it elsewhere, but for this particular context, it might not fit as I wish.

Comment: I'm confused. Service 1 stays running and you want to start another service (call it service 2) after service 1 ... stops? Starts? Calls one of the A, B, C, or D services?

Comment: Ocuh, I'm very sorry for the confusion. English is not my native tongue, but I will try to rephrase my point.
On the boot of my system: Service 1 is started and an app is displayed on screen.
This app allow to start Service A,B,C or D.
Once the user selects one of the services, Service 1 is stopped and the selected service is started.
The goal is that, when the newly running Service A,B,C or D is terminated (cleanly or uncleanly), we start Service 1 again.
This is the issue that triggers my question.